# How to change assets path in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, assets

I need to change the path from / to /something in my angular project.

I have added  "baseHref": "/something/" in /projects/my-project/architect/build/options of angular.json file and all paths are in /something/ except the asserts. The assets are still in /assets/fonts/.

How can I move the assets path from /assets/fonts/ to /something/assets/fonts/?

Please, Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to modify `assets` array at `project.my-projects.architect.build.options.assets` to be something like:

```
"assets": [
  "src/{SOMETHING}/assets", // This is the path you want to change
]
```

Comment: Thank you Paul Thorsen . But I have tried with "src/{SOMETHING}/assets" and I get the same error GET http://localhost:4200/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found).

Comment: How are you referencing the assets from your project?

Comment: I am using Kolkov, it seems that this is a not resolve problem: https://github.com/kolkov/angular-editor/issues/484
https://github.com/kolkov/angular-editor/issues/491
https://github.com/kolkov/angular-editor/issues/475

Answer (score 0):

i have a project angular with clean articture and my challenge was image address not found (404). because change address assets of src/assets into src/presentation/assets.

for solve it:

first go to angular.json and add presentation after src/ and add src/presentation/assets/images into "assets" array.

```
"assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/presentation/assets",
          "src/presentation/assets/images"
        ],
```

second go to element image in component and change address image:src of assets/1.png to presentation/assets/1.png

```
<img width="500px" src="presentation/assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
```